# Can spending a point of Willpower mitigate ANY compromise roll?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

On page 114 of DtD, the book says that a player can spend a point of Willpower to avoid compromise rolls in the case of using an Exploit. Am I correct in assuming that spending the point of Willpower is ONLY for Exploits? Not for Embeds that force a compromise roll or for assuming partial transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Willpower can only negate a Compromise roll triggered by Exploits**

DtD page 158, talking about invoking Exploits, speaks of a compromise roll under the Systems section: "The player can spend a point of Willpower to avoid this roll."

DtD page 124, in the sidebar about Embeds' designing: Some Embeds (eg, Voice of the Machine) may trigger a compromise roll.

No mention is made in this or the Systems section about mitigating any compromise roll triggered.

Because the description of Exploits acknowledges a way to mitigate Compromise, and the description of Embeds omits a way to mitigate compromise, the passage on compromise rolls on page 114 seems to be intended to be interpreted as such:

> *All* Exploits are compromises, but the player can spend a point of Willpower to avoid the compromise roll **in this case [alone].**

Bold emphasis mine.